# How to get a composite-control's child controls at design-time

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I am designing an ASP.NET v3.5 custom control based on CompositeControl.

However, I do NOT want to create my child controls via code, but rather as 
embedded HTML tag elements within the CompositeControl in the ASPX page, such as:

```
<cc:MyCompositeControl ID="MyControl">
    <asp:Label>Cat</asp:Label>
    <asp:Label>Cat</asp:Label>
</cc:MyCompositeControl>
```

At run time, MyControl.Controls  contains the two labels as expected.

At design time, MyControl.Controls is empty.

I need this information at design time for various reasons.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Actually it happened when we register the tagprefix in web.config and use the CompositeControl inside UserControl and another parent UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider taking a look at the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel` control in the `System.Web` DLL using Reflector. That will help you get some idea of what properties and what attribute decorations are necessary to provide the design-time support you need.